# find all invariant subspaces of $T_A$:$ \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

> Let $T_A$ :$ \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ be a linear transformation,
> $$A=\left(
>     \begin{matrix}
>     0 & -1 & 0 \\
>     1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 2 \\
>     \end{matrix} \right)
> $$
> find all invariant subspaces of $T_A$.

*0 dimension:* {0}
*3 dimension:* $\mathbb{R^3}$ itself.

*1 dimension:* The characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)(x^2 +1)$ therefore we have only 1 eigenvalue $\lambda= 2$ so the invariant subspace of dimension 1 must be the eigenspace of $\lambda= 2$ which is V=span{$(0,0,1)$}.

*2 dimension:* Here is where I need you help. How can I know how much invariant subspaces of  dimension 2 there is? and how can I find them?

Comment: Notice that $A \left( 1, 0, 0 \right) = \left( 0, 1, 0 \right)$ and $A \left( 0, 1, 0 \right) = - \left( 1, 0, 0 \right)$.

Comment: The Matrix is already in block structure. What happens to vector which belong to a certain block?

Comment: What can I infer from the fact that is in block structure? can you please extend about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the block structure of the matrix you can see that $U:=\langle (0,0,1)^T\rangle$ is a one-dimensional invariant subspace, and that $W:=\langle (1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T\rangle$ is a two-dimensional invariant subspace.

Can there be another one-dimensional invariant subspace, $\langle u \rangle$, say? This would mean that $Au\in\langle u\rangle$, so that $u$ would be an eigenvector. But you know that the only eigenvalue is $2$ and a simple calculation (solve the equations $Au=2u$) gives that $u$ must be a multiple of $(0,0,1)^T$, and so $\langle u\rangle=U$ after all.

Can there be another two-dimensional invariant subspace, $W_1$ say, with $W\not=W$? If so then $W\cap W_1$ is an invariant subspace. ( If you have doubts, note that $x\in W\cap W_1$ implies $x\in W$ and so $Ax\in W$, and similarly that $Ax\in W_1$.) As $W\not= W_1$ we have that $W+W_1>W$ and so $\dim (W+W_1)=3$. Hence $\dim W\cap W_1=\dim W +\dim W_1 -\dim (W+W_1)=1$. That is, $W\cap W_1$ is a one-dimensional invariant subspace, and so is $U$. But clearly $U$ is not a subspace of $W$, so we have a contradiction. Hence the only two-dimensional invariant subspace is $W$.

Comment: I understood everything except the part of the block structure. I'm not familiar with that, can you please extend? what  does it tell me? and why?

Comment: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} X & O\\O & Y\end{pmatrix}$ where $X$ is $r\times r$ and $Y$ is $s\times s$ then $A$ leaves invariant the subspace spanned by the first $r$ basis vectors, and the one spanned by the last $s$ basis vectors. [In your case $r=2$, $s=1$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help mate.